# Find $x$ and $y$ intercepts of $\dfrac{2x - 1}{x + 2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the rational function:

$$P(x) = \dfrac{2x - 1}{x + 2}.$$

How do I find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts? I'm quite confused. I don't know how to approach this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note for $x=-2$ the function is undefined so $x \not= -2$

To find the $x$ intercept(s), put $P(x)=0$, then,

$$\frac{2x-1}{x+2}=0$$
$$2x-1=0 \; \text{(remember }x\not=-2)$$
$$2x=1$$
$$x=\frac12$$

Now to find the $y$ intercept(s) put $x=0$, then,

$$\frac{-1}{2}=P(x)$$

So the $y$ intercept is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, John. I do have a question though. How does x = -2? Why is the function undefined and x does not equal to -2?

Comment: If $x=-2$ then we have $P(x)=\frac{something}{0}$ which is undefined as we can't divide by $0$. (We're not talking calculus here).

Comment: Thank you! Also, I'm a little confused when it comes to the y intercept? How is it -1/2?

Comment: Putting x=0 give $\frac{0 \cdot 2 -1}{0+2}=\frac{-1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The x-[intercept](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/intrcept.htm)s are where the graph crosses the x-axis i.e., where $P(x)=0$

Comment: @A'marie, "the y-intercepts are where the graph crosses the y-axis". Then, algebraically,"a y-intercept is a point on the graph where x is zero." More specifically,"a y-intercept is a point in the equation where the x-value is zero."